Do not save credentials with expo-auth-session
This might be a silly question, but still.
I am trying to use OAuth in my mobile app using doorkeeper (Rails) and expo-auth-session
I managed to setup the login as follows:
const [request, response, promptForLogin] = AuthSession.useAuthRequest(
  {
    clientId: "J_OgOWUEjFNOwUrKtq58QEqQ0cPEQv4pqs1kuNtMOyk",
    redirectUri,
    scopes: ["public"],
    prompt: AuthSession.Prompt.Login,
    usePKCE: true,
  },
  {
    revocationEndpoint: "http://localhost:3000/oauth/revoke",
    authorizationEndpoint: "http://localhost:3000/oauth/authorize",
    tokenEndpoint: "http://localhost:3000/oauth/token",
  }
);

I am storing the token I obtained, it's working fine and everything.
Then I have my logout method:
const handleLogout = () => {
  if (token === "") {
    return;
  }

  AuthSession.revokeAsync(
    {
      clientId: "J_OgOWUEjFNOwUrKtq58QEqQ0cPEQv4pqs1kuNtMOyk",
      token,
    },
    {
      revocationEndpoint: "http://localhost:3000/oauth/revoke",
    }
  );

  setToken("");
};

When I log-out, I see on Rails logs that the token was revoked and also I see that the logout method is working (token is set to "").
However, when I try to login again, the WebBrowser does not ask for credentials again, it just automatically does the entire process. How to prevent this behavior for happening?
I want that, anytime an user logout, they need to re-type their email + password.

The session still exists in the browser. The end user logout is initiated by redirecting to "end_session_endpoint". See https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-rpinitiated-1_0.html for details.

I'm in similar situation as you. It is quite astonishing that the discoveryDocument has a property called endSessionEndpoint. But I searched the source code and didn't find any method that calls it.
This is my dirty work around for now. I'm using AWS Cognito hosted UI. The revokeAsync call is pretty much useless as the user can click login and is directly logged in without entering credentials. What makes the logout work is "await WebBrowser.openAuthSessionAsync(endSessionUrl, redirectUri);"
I hope expo auth fixes this issue. The annoying part of my solution is that when user clicks logout the device prompts "App wants to use amazon-auth... to Sign In". The user clearly clicked sign-out haha. But this works!
const redirectUri = AuthSession.makeRedirectUri({
  scheme: "myapp"
});

endSessionEndpoint: userPoolUrl + "/logout"


   
     const logout = async () => {
        if (!authTokens) {
          return;
        }
        // Logout using AuthSession
        const endSessionUrl = `${discoveryDocument.endSessionEndpoint}?client_id=${clientId}&logout_uri=${redirectUri}`;
        await AuthSession.revokeAsync(
          {
            token: authTokens.refreshToken as string
          },
          discoveryDocument
        );
    
        await WebBrowser.openAuthSessionAsync(endSessionUrl, redirectUri);
    
        setAuthTokens(null);
        setUserProfile(null);
      };

